# download count29.php whene loading site

Tags: errors

When my site is loading file count29.php to be downloaded from the site avondov.ru. This makes the site not loading completely and sometimes redirect to 404 page not found

how can i do ignore this error?

my web site is : adinehbajestan.ir

Answer (score 1):

Never ignore errors, errors are for fixing.

A quick google of this gives me this malware:

http://sucuri.net/malware/malware-entry-mwiframehd37

Basically your site has been hacked/compromised. You need to look at your security, make sure everything is up to date and watertight, and check your code for nonvalidated data and unchecked file processing.